# Angular SSR with @nguniversal and a custom webpack for PostCSS support

Tags: angular, webpack, server-side-rendering, tailwind-css, postcss

My Angular 10.2.1 app has PostCSS support in my .scss files using a custom webpack builder, which works perfectly fine in SPA mode.

**angular.json**

```
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
let plugins = [
  require('postcss-import'),
  require('tailwindcss'),
  require('autoprefixer'),
]

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          syntax: 'postcss-scss',
          plugins: () => plugins
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I decided to add SSR support with `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` as per official documentation but when I try to serve the SSR version I get the error:

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected ";".
   ╷
90 │         @apply border-pink-200 !important;
   │                                ^
   ╵
  src/app/app.component.scss 90:32  root stylesheet
```

Which makes perfect sense because the SSR artefacts that `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` adds to angular.json do not use my custom webpack config. I've looked under both [`@nguniversal/builders`](https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/builders) and [`@angular-builders`](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) but couldn't find any information on how to load a custom webpack file for nguniversal.

Here is my full `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "hp24-frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "hp24",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/hp24-frontend/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles"
              ]
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "browserTarget": "hp24-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "hp24-frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hp24-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/variables/_colors.scss",
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json",
              "tsconfig.server.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "hp24-frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "hp24-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/hp24-frontend/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hp24-frontend:build",
            "serverTarget": "hp24-frontend:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "hp24-frontend:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "hp24-frontend:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hp24-frontend:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "hp24-frontend:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "hp24-frontend"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["googlemaps"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "debug": true
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7):

The solution was to replace `@angular-devkit/build-angular:server` with `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server` in the server artefact that nguniversal adds to `angular.json` like so:

```
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/hp24-frontend/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
```

This seems to also fix the `serve-ssr` and `prerender` artefacts because they internally call `server`. So now I can use all the nguniversal npm scripts with my own custom webpack config.